# Error con PhpMyAdmin: "¡Se detectaron algunos errores en el servidor! Revise el pie de esta ventana."

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Cuando intento examinar el contenido de una tabla en PhpMyAdmin, tarda un poco intentando mostrar el contenido y me devuelve el mensaje "Se detectaron algunos errores en el servidor! Revise el pie de esta ventana", como se muestra en la imagen.

- Desde la terminal de MySQL se obtienen los datos de la tabla.
- Actualicé PHPMyAdmin, reinicié XAMPP pero el problema persiste.

[image: Error]

Comment: Y qué texto aparece en la parte que te indica dicho mensaje

Comment: Absolutamente nada, sólo el check del mensaje "Enviar reporte automáticamente la próxima vez".

Comment: A mí también me ha ocurrido esto. ¿Encontraste la solución al problema?

Answer (score 1):

No se si ya pudiste resolver el problema, a mi me ocurrió lo mismo al actualizar a la versión 4.9.2 y cada vez que intentaba consultar una tabla con valores foraneos saltaba ese error a pesar que si mostraba los resultados. Lo resolví dando click en "Datos de sesión vacios" que es el icono que esta justo debajo del logo de phpMyAdmin en el sidebar, al lado del home, ojala pueda ayudar este tip.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso se daba el problema porque estaba utilizando la ultima version de PHP y mysql no soporta la ultima versión de PHP, lo que hice fue vovler una version anterior a PHP (7.1) y me funcionó, espero te sirva